# How to use custom icon font in angular

Tags: angular, fonts, angular-material

At the moment we use mat-icon component with angular material icons. However, we want to create our custom icon font with the customer's branding and use it in angular. I used https://icomoon.io/ and created our own font. But how do we use it in angular project and can we still use mat-icon compoment.

Comment: Angular Material documentation explains here: https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview. Specifically *By default, <mat-icon> expects the Material icons font. (You will still need to include the HTML to load the font and its CSS, as described in the link). You can specify a different font by setting the fontSet input to either the CSS class to apply to use the desired font, or to an alias previously registered with MatIconRegistry.registerFontClassAlias.*

Comment: https://onecodex.ch/blog/registerfontawesomeiconsforusagewithmaterialmaticon demonstrates importing font-awesome to be used with material icons

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Let me suggest the simplest way

1. Place your `yourfont.ttf` into `src/assets`
2. Add it into `src/style.css` in this way:

   ```css
   @font-face {
     font-family: 'MyFont';
     src: url('../assets/myfont.ttf');
   }
   ```
3. Use the new font wherever you need, for example

   ```css
   body {
     font-family: 'MyFont';
   }
   ```

That's all.